# VB.net - Populate Listbox with user from the same location

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, listbox

So I have a very simple Access db with

- UserID, Office, Show
- JaneDoe, Austin, yes
- JohnDoe, Huston, yes
- MikeSmith, Austin, no
- KimSmith, Waco, yes

Etc..90 more like this.

I want to see who the is logged in. See what office the user is in.

Then I want to populate the listbox with other UserID that Match the Current users office, also only add the user if they have Yes in the Show column.

I can get the current user but from there I'm just lost.

My thought process is

```
‘Count the rows in the table
Rows = Table.rows.count
i=1
For i to rows
    If CurrentUser = Table (i,column1(UserID))
        UserOffice = Table(i,Column2(office))
    End if
Next
'Second loop find other users with same office
‘and only add those that have show as yes
i=1
For i to rows
   If Table(i,Column2(office)) = UserOffice then
       If Table(i,Column4)= "Yes" Then
           listbox1.items.add Table(i,Column1(UserID))
       End if
   End If
Next
```

Just interacting with the Table is frustrating to me at this point. I have no real start to interact with the table. I’m not understanding other examples online.

I would normally hard code everything but there are too many changes to push out a new app every time someone moves offices.
It has been a 15 years since I used VB so everything I know from VB is deprecated or lost to the sands of time.

Please help!

Comment: You can set the DataTable as the DataSource of the ListBox. Define a `DisplayMember` (the name of the Column which provides the values displayed), a `ValueMember` (the name of the Column which provides an associated value), then filter the `DataTable` using its `DefaultView`, e.g., `[DataTable].DefaultView.Filer = $"UserID = {CurrentUser} AND Show = True"`

Comment: Sorry I feel like such a noob. How do I reference the DataTable? Everything associated with my data is Dataset, TableAdapter and I'm not seeing Defaultview as an option.

Comment: You use a DataAdapter to fill either a DataSet or a DataTable. If you `.Fill()` a  DataSet, then you add a DataTable to the DataSet, so your DataTable will be `[myDataSet].Tables(0)` or `[myDataSet].Tables("TheTableName")`. If you have just one DataTable (so, you don't have relations between tables), fill a DataTable instead of a DataSet. In any case, you use this DataTable as the DataSource of Controls that have a `DataSource` Property.

Comment: So Current user can have several UserID's? The Access table has 4 columns. What ties the Current User to certain UserID's?

Comment: No, the UserID is just a list of all the Username's in the org. There are say 8 different offices. Some of the userID's are say clerks I don't want populating in the list.  Example A clerk clicks the button I want to fill the listbox with all the agents in the clerks office. @mary Does that make since?

Comment: That last comment certainly doesn't match up with what you said in your question. It seems to me that you need to edit your question and provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of what you're actually trying to achieve. It sounds like you want to filter by `Office` and `Title` but there's no mention of that in the question. Also, you need to work out where your issue actually is. Is your issue querying a database, filtering a `DataTable` or populating a `ListBox`, because they are all very different things. Work out what you actually can do and what you can't.

Comment: Is that clearer explanation? @jmcilhinney

Comment: Can you please clarify if you mean VB.NET or VBA?

Comment: Are you asking about Access or VB.NET?

Comment: Using VB.NET to access data from an access dB.